# UIImage isn't showing up in UIScrollView

Tags: arrays, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview, cocoapods

Im grabbing the photos from library using a cocoa pod called BSImagePicker. The Images are then stored into a photoArray. I want to take those images from the array and present them in an image view that's held inside the scrollView. However the images aren't showing up at all.

This is what I've currently tried.

This is the code that the cocoa pod uses to store images into the array:

```
func openImagePicker() {
    let vc = BSImagePickerViewController()

    self.bs_presentImagePickerController(
        vc, 
        animated: true,
        select: { (assest: PHAsset) -> Void in },
        deselect: { (assest: PHAsset) -> Void in },
        cancel: { (assest: [PHAsset]) -> Void in },
        finish: { (assest: [PHAsset]) -> Void in
            for i in 0..<assest.count {
                self.SelectedAssets.append(assest[i])
            }

            self.convertAssetToImages()
        }, 
        completion: nil
    )
    print(photoArray)
    setupImages(photoArray)
}
```

this is the code that converts asset to image

```
extension addImages {

    func convertAssetToImages() -> Void {

        if SelectedAssets.count != 0{

            for i in 0..<SelectedAssets.count{

                let manager = PHImageManager.default()
                let option = PHImageRequestOptions()

                var thumbnail = UIImage()

                option.isSynchronous = true

                let width = scrollView.frame.width
                let height = scrollView.frame.height

                manager.requestImage(for: SelectedAssets[i], targetSize: CGSize(width: width, height: height), contentMode: .aspectFill, options: option, resultHandler: {(result,info) -> Void in
                    thumbnail = result!
                })

                let data = thumbnail.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)
                let newImage = UIImage(data: data! as Data)
                self.photoArray.append(newImage! as UIImage)
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

this code takes image from photo array into scrollview

```
func setupImages(_ images: [UIImage]){
    for a in 0..<photoArray.count {

        let theImage = UIImageView()
        theImage.image = self.photoArray[a]
        let xPosition = UIScreen.main.bounds.width * CGFloat(a)
        self.scrollView.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: 0, width: self.scrollView.frame.width, height: self.scrollView.frame.height)
        theImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        self.scrollView.contentSize.width = self.scrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(a + 1)
        self.scrollView.addSubview(theImage)

      }
  }
```

I have no idea why it isn't working.

Comment: Where do you set the frame of the images?

Comment: @SlavenkoMiljic thank you, thats what the issue was, in the setup images I set the scroll view frame not the image frame!